# is every subgroup of a semi-direct product of groups a semi-direct product of subgroups?

Tags: group-theory

The title pretty much says it all... anyway... let $G$ be a semi-direct product of $N$ by $Q$, and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.

Can one always find subgroups $N_1$ and $Q_1$, of $N$ and $Q$ respectively, such that $H$ is the semi-direct product of these two groups?

If not in general, can one say anything about the following cases:
i) $G = \text{GL}(n,K)$, i.e. the general linear group of dimension $n$ over some field $K$
ii) $G = \text{Aff}(E)$, i.e. the group of all affine motions of some (finite dimensional) linear space

thx in advance

Comment: For case i) do you really want $G = \mathrm{GL}(n, K)$ or did you intend to write $Q = \mathrm{GL}(n, K)$?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm embarresed by the triviallity of the counterexamples. @Jug: No I don't, why (honestly I don't understand the question, I think...) Also: About the infinite cyclyc subgroups of Aff(E)...it supersedes my imagination, when I think of the homgenized version of Aff(E), i.e. the embedding into GL(n+1,E), how such a subgroup, i.e. one that is not of the form mentioned in my first post, can arise. Therefor I'd really appreciate it, if Jim Belk, or someone else, could elaborate on that. Lastly: I was thinking about GL(n,E) being the semi-direct product of SL(E) by K*.

Comment: (The previous comment was converted from a "comment as answer" posted by the OP, and was edited slightly for length. 10K users can see the original below.)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what others have said, let me remark that it is not even true that any subgroup is *isomorphic to* a semi-direct product of subgroups (note that this weaker notion does take care of the counterexamples given, since the diagonal group is isomorphic to a semi-direct product of subgroups).

Here is an example: let $D$ be the dihedral group of order $2^{n+1}$:
$$
D=\langle x,c | x^2=c^{2^n}=1, xcx=c^{-1}\rangle.
$$
Let $H=\langle h| h^{2^n}=1\rangle$ act on $D$ via $x^h = cx$, $c^h=c$, form the semi-direct product $G=D\rtimes H$. Then, you can check that the element $xh$ has order $2^{n+1}$, so the cyclic group generated by it is not isomorphic to a semi-direct product of any subgroups of $D$ and/or $H$.

Comment: Do there exist any such counter-examples in a direct product?

Answer (score 4):

The general answer to your question is no.  For example, the [Klein four-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group) is the direct product (and hence semidirect product) of two cyclic groups, but the (diagonal) subgroup $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ is not the product of subgroups.

Indeed, I would say that almost any example of a semidirect product will not have the property that you mention.  It is certainly not the case for $\text{GL}(n,K)$ or $\text{Aff}(E)$, though I'm not sure exactly what semidirect product structure you have in mind for $\text{GL}(n,K)$.  But I can tell you that $\text{Aff}(\mathbb{R})$ has plenty of infinite cyclic subgroups that are not of the form you mention.

Answer (score 2):

For the direct product $G \times G$ ($G$ being any nontrivial group), the diagonal subgroup is clearly not a semidirect product of subgroups of $G$.